What is meant by fluid pressure?
I understand that fluid pressure means the pressure the fluid exerts on some surface, but what surface are we talking about? Is it the force exerted on tubing or the fluid itself or are these both the same somehow?

Does the answer “any conceptual surface, sufficiently small that pressure variations are negligible” resolve the question? If not, what remains unclear?

It's the pressure on the device that is measuring it.

@Chemomechanics wouldn't the pressure be different depending on what conceptual surface we choose? If this conceptual surface is the cross section of the tubing I would imagine the force on it would be different than if it were the tubing wall.

Under hydrostatic conditions, the pressure on all surfaces of arbitrary orientation at a specified location in the fluid is the same.  If the fluid is deforming, the force per unit area varies with the orientation of the fluid due to the viscous contribution to the stress tensor (Google Newtonian Fluid)).
